# Getting boolean isAdmin values using servlets in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

So I'm just starting to work on MVC architecture in school, working with jsp, servlets, java, db etc... I have a simple login form with name and password, and a database with users with the values (name, password, and isAdmin(boolean)) When a user enters their name and password, how would I compare the login name and password with whether they are an admin or not? The servlet redirects to admin.jsp page if it's an admin, or to user.jsp if it's just a user. Should I store within a session and do comparisons from there? I'm hoping this makes sense without the code, otherwise I will post if more info is needed.

Comment: The only work around I'm using is looking at who is an Admin in the DB and then doing a if statement saying if(request.getParameter("username").equals("AdminName"); but I really don't like that. Seems innefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT isAdmin FROM users WHERE name LIKE '"+nameValue+"' AND password LIKE '"+passValue");
if(rs.next()){
    if(rs.getBoolean()){
    // redirect to admin.jsp
    }
    else {
    // redirect to user.jsp
    }
} else {
 // user or password invalid
}
```

I would do something like that, don't know if it fits what you're asking for

Comment: I wouldn't do it all from the DB class but this gave me the right idea. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of some help :D